# How to change start point of Major Gridlines in an excel chart?

Tags: excel, charts, excel-2013

I have a chart that has data starting in September 2011 until April 2019 (monthly data). I have plotted it on a chart and put the year of the data on the x axis. The cosmetic issue I have is that the first text label on the x axis ("2012") is shown nearly half way through the first 'major gridline' point.

What I want is for each year to line up with each 'major gridline'.  This would involve starting the first major gridline 5 data points in - not 12 as I have as standard.  For the life of me I cannot work out how to change this.

I know I can change the data so that my x axis "starts" at 2011.  The issue with this is that the value points that are unavailable (Jan-11 to Aug-11) are set at 0 and therefore mess up the trendline.

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

[image: example of the chart]

Comment: Please share a screenshot of this if possible and some sample data to recreate your problem.

Comment: Have a set of data that starts in 2011, all with a value of 0 - this will then set your labels and not upset the trendline as that is based on the real data starting in 2012.

Comment: @JvdV shared the screenshot - sorry for the low quality

Comment: @SolarMike it does unfortunately - the trend line equation proves there is a change

Comment: @Boswell you missed my ponit, I did this before we had a combination of trendlines to give our final result - we used 6 charts overlaid on each other but fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try as below?

[image]

I'm thinking just add the missing months to the graph's data and have empty values. Empty values don't seem to affect your trendline.

Comment: I'm very impressed that you put a gif into the comments (clearly I don't use stackoverflow very often!). However, I do believe the trendline is changing - although the general direction is the same, when you get technical it is quite different. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @Boswell, have you tried to see if there is any difference? I haven't but I find it highly unlikely. Either way, glad to have helped

Comment: you might be right actually. I will try again on Monday.

Answer (score 2):

So, just to prove my comment of a dummy data line and added a trendline to each with the formula shown - which happens to have the same values.

[image]

Comment: Okay I get it now - I will give this ago and let you know

Comment: Yep it worked - the formula was changing for me sill but only because the number of values was increased by 8. The end result is exactly the same though :) thank you for you help

Comment: Excellent - hope it all comes together.