# How to remove dummy dates on a excel chart

Tags: excel, graph, dummy-data

I have a problem with dummy dates on my chart, anyone to assist me
I want to remove 1 December to 05 December since they are not in my data

[image]

Comment: Perhaps try something like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55867707/4961700

Comment: Edit your post, I think there is a typo, you have highlighted in the screenshot from 1st Dec till 5th Dec, where as you wrote 1st Nov till 5th Dec.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the error. As for the solution, how do I Apply this to a big dataset? its quite cumbersome, do you perhaps have any other solution for me?